# Get max from a sub array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a question, lets say I have an array:

```
var array = new int[] { 7, 16, 4, 9, 865, 3, -8, 56};
```

I want to get the max value **from** index (lets say index 4), how do I do that?
Is there something like:

```
array.fromIndex(4).max()
```

also, I tried to go simple and did

```
(array + 4).max()
```

but get an error

> "operator '+' cannot be applied"

Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: `array.Skip(4).Max()`?

Comment: All of your 4 questions have been answered with quite good and helpful responses. You should return the favour by marking them as correct answers. Since you never have done it the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) article should help. And the [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) post has even a picture. Good day

Answer (score 4):

> also, I tried to go simple and did
>       `(array + 4).max()`
>   but get an error "operator '+' cannot be applied", why is that?

In C# `array` is not a pointer that you can calculate with. So the operator `+` is not defined to perform such an operation.

If you want to start searching the max value from a certain index on you can skip all the values up to this point:

```
int maxValue = array.Skip(4).Max();
```

**EDIT:**
Inspired by the suggested of @jdphenix in the comment:

If you want to have more control over the range where you want to search the maximum then the `Take` method could be of great help. This combination would allow you to set the range of your sub array:

```
var array = new int[] { 7, 16, 4, 9, 865, 3, -8, 56 };
int startIndex = 4;
int numberOfElements = 3;
array.Skip(startIndex).Take(numberOfElements).Max();
```

if you want to specify the start- and end-index it would look like this:

```
int startIndex = 4;
int endIndex = 7;
array.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex).Max();
```

Comment: Additionally, given the question in the title (How to get a max from a range), mentioning that's possible combining `Take()` and `Skip()` is useful.